# elasticsearch-keystore not populated by kubernetes InitContainer

Tags: azure, kubernetes, elasticsearch

I try to add a snapshot repository using the Azure Repository Plugin to an elasticsearch instance running on Azure (with K8s) deployed through helm using the chart from helm.elastic.com.
The chart is patched to use a self-built image `myprivaterepo:elasticsearch-azure:7.9.2` containing the Azure Repository Plugin and now I'm stuck adding the Azure credentials to the elasticsearch-keystore.

I added a secret containing the azure credentials and a second init-container to the elasticsearch statefulset to populate the keystore from the secret:

```
  - command:
    - sh
    - -c
    - |
      whoami
      echo $AZURE_ACCOUNT | bin/elasticsearch-keystore add --stdin --force azure.client.default.account
      echo $AZURE_SAS_TOKEN | bin/elasticsearch-keystore add --stdin --force azure.client.default.sas_token
      ls -l config
      bin/elasticsearch-keystore list
    env:
    - name: AZURE_ACCOUNT
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: account
          name: snapshot-secret
    - name: AZURE_SAS_TOKEN
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: sas
          name: snapshot-secret
    image: myprivateregistry/elasticsearch-azure-7.9.2
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: update-keystore
    resources: {}
    securityContext:
      runAsGroup: 1000
      runAsNonRoot: true
      runAsUser: 1000
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
```

The `command` is slightly extended to check problems with permission.
The Init Container runs sucessfully, producing the following output.

```
$ kubectl logs elasticsearch-master-2 -c update-keystore

elasticsearch
total 32
-rw-rw---- 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch  428 Mar 24 09:01 elasticsearch.keystore
-rw-rw---- 1 elasticsearch root            53 Sep 23 00:49 elasticsearch.yml
-rw-rw---- 1 elasticsearch root          2301 Sep 23 00:43 jvm.options
drwxrwxr-x 2 elasticsearch root          4096 Sep 23 00:47 jvm.options.d
-rw-rw---- 1 elasticsearch root          7734 Sep 23 00:49 log4j2.properties
-rw-rw---- 1 elasticsearch root           473 Sep 23 00:47 role_mapping.yml
-rw-rw---- 1 elasticsearch root           197 Sep 23 00:47 roles.yml
-rw-rw---- 1 elasticsearch root             0 Sep 23 00:47 users
-rw-rw---- 1 elasticsearch root             0 Sep 23 00:47 users_roles
azure.client.default.account
azure.client.default.sas_token
keystore.seed
```

The first line is the user which ran the command, the list shows `/usr/share/elasticsearch/config` followed by the output from `bin/elasticsearch-keystore list` which correctly shows the added keys.

My problem is that in the running elasticsearch container, the keystore is empty

```
$ kubectl exec -ti elasticsearch-master-2 -- bin/elasticsearch-keystore list
keystore.seed
```

same for `-master-0` and `-master-1`.

I looked at several blogs and howtos, all doing it quite the same way, but I cannot find the mistake. Some use the elasticsearch controller which is currently no option and should not really be the showstopper here.

[A Guide to Elasticsearch Snapshots](https://joshua-robinson.medium.com/a-guide-to-elasticsearch-snapshots-565017630638)
[Keystore file created by initContainer is not accessible by the elasticsearch user #3332](https://github.com/elastic/cloud-on-k8s/issues/3332)

I, too, deployed the chart into our private K8s cluster running elasticsearch 7.11.2 with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. I overlooked that the InitContainer and the real container need to mount a volume to share the generated secrets.

By adding a volume and properly mounting it to the container like this, the keystore has the expected values within the container.

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: keystore
        emptyDir: {}

      containers:
        volumeMount:
        - name: keystore
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.keystore
          subPath: elasticsearch.keystore

      initContainer:
      - command:
        [... as above ...]
        cp -a /usr/share/elastichsearch/config/elasticsearch.keystore /tmp/keystore

        volumeMounts:
        - name: keystore
          mountPath: /tmp/keystore
```